# Use Guzzle in own project including another project also contain Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I created an project (let's just call it "myproject") which make use of Guzzle 7.0 itself, and should also use another project called "keycloak-admin-client". I tried to use it this way:

```
require('/opt/myproject/inc/guzzle7.0/vendor/autoload.php');
require('/opt/myproject/inc/keycloak-admin-client/vendor/autoload.php');
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
...
```

I can use my own HTTP-Requests with Guzzle 7 included, but in the moment i try to use the Keycloak client i get this errormessage:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri::resolve() in /op/myproject/inc/keycloak-admin-client/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle-services/src/Serializer.php:161
```

So maybe it's not allowed/possible to use Guzzle two times this way? Or is it the mix of versions? (Keycloak Client uses Guzzle 6.0).

Comment: When using composer there will be either 7 or 6 version installed, but not both. Upgrade/downgrade one part of project so that all parts are using same Guzzle version

Comment: I did try this, but without any success.

Comment: You just **can't** use same lib of two different versions in same project. Any autoload will either loads 6 or 7 version and never another one

Comment: Even if i use the same version for my project as in the Keycloak project i get the error above. I guess the problem is this autoloader.  It uses random names and so such things like require_once do not work.

Comment: You should use composer autoloader